# Is the attenuation constant in EM wave equation a vector or tensor?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields

In general, an EM wave within a lossy medium is expressed as
$\mathbf{E}=\mathbf{E_0}e^{-\gamma_x x-\gamma_y y-\gamma_z z}$.
If we consider $\mathbf{\gamma}=\gamma_x \hat{x}+\gamma_y \hat{y}+\gamma_z \hat{z}$ and $\mathbf{r}=x\hat{x}+y\hat{y}+z\hat{z}$, the above equation is expressed as
$\mathbf{E}=\mathbf{E_0}e^{-\gamma\cdot\mathbf{r}}=\mathbf{E_0}e^{-(\alpha+j\beta)\cdot\mathbf{r}}$, because $\gamma=\alpha+j\beta$. $\beta$ is also considered as a vector and due to the dot product between the $\beta$ and $\mathbf{r}$ the phase propagation of the wave takes place in three-dimensional space. As the dot product is operating over the $(\alpha+j\beta)$, an $\alpha\cdot \mathbf{r}$ should also be expected. But for that, the $\alpha$ must be a vector. But, $\alpha$ contains terms associated with the permittivity and permeability which are tensors. Therefore, I am a bit confused about whether the $\alpha$ also be a vector or tensor?

Please help me to understand the right thing.

Comment: start by cleaning up notation.  your $\gamma$ is a vector (but not indicated as such) as it has components along all 3 axes, so that $\gamma=\alpha+j\beta$ should also be a vector.